# Not able to listen to aws ip configured inside nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

My configuration is as shown below:

**node-app(/etc/nginx/sites-enabled)**

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name http://ec2-54-202-135-40.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;


        location / {
                proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000";

        }
}
```

**hosts(/etc/)**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 ec2-54-202-135-40.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
127.0.0.1 ip-172-31-33-245 # bitnami-hosts-patch
```

Here when I type **sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start** command, everything works fine, but somehow when I type **http://ec2-54-202-135-40.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/foodtrucklist** instead of **http://ec2-54-202-135-40.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/foodtrucklist**, I am not able to get anything.

Here I have setup bitnami mean stack on aws ubuntu which comes with apache.

When I run sudo lsof -i :80 , I get the following result:

```
httpd.bin 1992   root    4u  IPv6   9757      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd.bin 1997 daemon    4u  IPv6   9757      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd.bin 1998 daemon    4u  IPv6   9757      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd.bin 3390 daemon    4u  IPv6   9757      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Comment: http://ec2-54-202-135-40.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/foodtrucklist seems to work fine

Comment: ok,thanks. It has started working for me as well